# Datatables properties missing after reloading page

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, html-table

I am trying to display table with DataTables properties.

On clicking the "Show all data" link I am loading a jsp page which has query and then the `<td>` data for table but datatable properties are missing. I could not see alternative rows color and Search functionality.

Please help me how to get the Datatables properties to the RefreshRecentData.JSP as well on load. Below is my JS:

```
function updateData()
{

$("#loadAllData").html("");
if ($("#dataLink").text()==="Show all data") {
      $('#change_heading').hide();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RefreshRecentData.jsp",
        data: {Param: 'PR'},
        dataType:'html',
        cache:false,
        success:function(html){
            $("#loadAllData").html(html);
            $("#dataLink").text("Show only few data");

      }});
}
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<th class="fieldName" nowrap="nowrap" align="center" style="width:60%;text-align: left" title="Recent Data">Recent Data<span align="right" ><a id="dataLink" style="cursor:pointer;" style="padding-left: 600px;"onclick="updateData()"><u>Show all data</u></a></span>
```

Here is my table structure

```
<table id="table_id" class="display" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <th class="althead" style="width:7%;">Date</th>
        <th class="althead" style="width:9%;">Apps</th>

        </tr>

    </thead>
    <!--Queries and getting data setting in bean etc here -->
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Apps</td>
    </tr>
```

Datatables

```
$('table_id').dataTable( {
                "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "sScrollY": "250px",
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "bScrollCollapse": false,
                "iDisplayLength": 4,
                "aLengthMenu": [4,5,6,8]
            } );
```

Comment: You really lack a `<tbody>`

Comment: Your table html is invalid. You need a `thead` with proper `tr` tags, same with `tbody`.